# Examples folder not showing in ls output

Tags: nautilus, ls

I have just installed Ubuntu 16.04 desktop on my machine and I have been getting to know it better. I used `ls -la` in my home directory. The result is as expected. I have Downloads, Desktop folders etc. along with hidden folders and files. But I realized that the "Examples" folder is not listed which I could see from nautilus. I was wondering why this may be.

On the Examples folder
`right click -> properties` showed that it's type is "Folder (inode/directory)" which is not very exciting because the same goes for the Downloads folder. Yet again "Examples" is clearly some sort of link, from nautilus it leads to `/usr/share/example-content`.
Also With `right click -> properties -> Permissions` I have seen that both the owner and the group of Examples folder are root, whereas it is not the case with the Downloads folder, perhaps this is relevant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "Examples" object you're talking about in your home folder is neither a directory nor a regular symbolic link ("symlink"). It is a .desktop file, similar to those which define your application launcher icons.

You should see a `examples.desktop` text file in your home folder with `ls`, which gets displayed like a link to a directory in the Files explorer GUI.

It's contents are shown below (abbreviated by omitting all but the "en_GB" translations). You can get them by e.g. typing `cat examples.desktop` in the terminal.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=1.0
Type=Link
Name=Examples
Name[en_GB]=Examples
# ...
Comment=Example content for Ubuntu
Comment[en_GB]=Example content for Ubuntu
# ...
URL=file:///usr/share/example-content/
Icon=folder
X-Ubuntu-Gettext-Domain=example-content
```

If you have a look at the `Type` and `URL` field, you see that this file represents a link to the `/usr/share/example-content/` directory. Its display name gets adjusted according to your selected language.